"Deriving" the covariant derivative
Suppose we are working in scalar QED with Lagrangian
$$\mathscr{L} = (D_\mu \phi)(D^\mu \phi)^* - \frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}.$$
I now want to find the form of the covariant derivative $D_\mu$ that leaves the Lagrangian invariant under the gauge transformation $$ \phi \rightarrow e^{i \alpha(x)} \phi \qquad \qquad A_\mu \rightarrow A_\mu + \frac{1}{g}\partial_\mu \alpha.$$
To me it seems that this is sort of a backwards problem, since usually we define $D_\mu$ and the gauge field appropriately to preserve gauge invariance.
In any case, for this problem, is there any way of "deriving" $D_\mu$ without a priori demanding that its form is like $D_\mu \sim \partial_\mu + A_\mu$?
EDIT: Just using partial derivatives, I'm obtaining
$$(\partial_\mu \phi')( \partial^\mu \phi')^* = \partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi^* +i (\partial_\mu \alpha)\phi \partial^\mu \phi^*-i\partial_\mu \phi(\partial^\mu \alpha) \phi^*+ (\partial_\mu \alpha)(\partial^\mu \alpha)\phi \phi^*$$ Can I just start plugging in $\partial_\mu \alpha = g(A'_\mu - A_\mu)$ in this expression and derive the covariant derivative?

If it seems people are supposing the forms of covariant derivatives is likely because they've been known for so long that it's easier to demonstrate how that form already works. But have you tried just showing that if you assume the usual local gauge transformations that you get that covariant derivatives for say the QED lagrangian?

The form comes out quite naturally by inserting the gauge transformed field into the Lagrangian with the usual derivative, and then checking which terms need to be countered to ensure gauge invariance.

I think you just need to find an operator $D_{\mu}$ such that
$$
D'_{\mu}\phi' = e^{i\beta}D_{\mu}\phi.
$$
For some arbitrary phase $\beta$. The normal derivative is a starting point.
$$
\partial_{\mu} \phi' = i\phi e^{i\alpha}\partial_{\mu}\alpha + e^{i\alpha}\partial_{\mu}\phi
$$
$$
e^{-i\alpha}\partial_{\mu}\phi' - \partial_{\mu}\phi = ig(A_\mu'-A_\mu)\phi
$$
Separating the primed and unprimed terms, we get
$$
\partial_\mu \phi -igA_\mu\phi = e^{-i\alpha}(\partial_{\mu} \phi' - igA_\mu'\phi')
$$
So we see that the operator $D_\mu = \partial_{\mu} - igA_\mu$ do the job.
